# Should the head of a linked list be a dummy node?

Tags: vb6, linked-list, head

I'm currently writing a program that (as of right now) utilizes about five linked lists, and there's about 50 functions that modify or otherwise use those linked lists.  I am somewhat torn on how exactly the head node should be implemented.

**Implementation #1** Using a dummy head node

If I create a dummy head node, the headNode never has to be deleted, even if there is no data for that linked list to represent. Below are two different possible linked lists showing this idea.

```
Format: (object)--name_of_pointer_to_next_object--> (next object)
(headNode)--headNode.pNext--> (Nothing/NULL)
(headNode)--headNode.pNext--> (dataNode1)--dataNode1.pNext--> (dataNode2)--dataNode2.pNext--> (Nothing/NULL)
```

The benefit of this implementation is that, for functions that work with the linked lists, they don't have to have special code for the case where the head node is `Nothing` or (in c++), `NULL`.  Below is an example of appending a node onto the end of the linked list using this implementation.

```
Public Function AppendNode(theLinkedList as NODE_, theNewNode as NODE_)
    dim lastNode as NODE_

    Set lastNode = theLinkedList

    Do While Not lastNode.pNext Is Nothing
        Set lastNode = lastNode.pNext
    Loop

    Set lastNode.pNext = theNewNode 
End Function
```

**Implementation #2** headNode can be deleted

If I allow the headNode to be deleted, this poses problems and increases the volume of code that I have to write.  Below is the same set of data, except this time the head is a legitimate node that contains data.

```
Format: (object)--name_of_pointer_to_next_object--> (next object)
(Nothing/NULL)
(dataNode1)--dataNode1.pNext--> (dataNode2)--dataNode1.pNext--> (Nothing/NULL)
```

And here is the same function, except that this time it has to beware of the possibility that the head node is `Nothing`/`NULL`.

```
Public Function AppendNode(theLinkedList as NODE_, theNewNode as NODE_)
    dim lastNode as NODE_

    If theLinkedList Is Nothing Then
        Set theLinkedList = theNewNode 
    Else
        Set lastNode = theLinkedList

        Do While Not lastNode.pNext Is Nothing
            Set lastNode = lastNode.pNext
        Loop

        Set lastNode.pNext = theNewNode 
    End If
End Function
```

Obviously, I am leaning towards Implementation #1.  It requires at least 4 less lines of code each time I want to use the linked lists (considering the fact that I will do this hundreds of times, you can multiply that 4 lines by 300 or so; e.g. it will save me from writing 1,200 lines of code), AND perhaps most importantly, it will cut down on the amount of state my program has.  All of the possible states that my program will be in will only require me to look for `pNext Is Nothing`, and reducing the amount of state is greatly appreciated at this point because this program is going to be a monster that will end up being around 20k lines of rather complicated code that has to deal with a lot of state.

Am I wrong in thinking that Implementation #1 is the best way to do this?  I can't come up with a single reason why Implementation #2 would be superior.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to reuse the VBA.Collection class? That way you save lots of lines of code reinventing the wheel. If you want to ensure you have a properly typed interface, you can always create a thin wrapper class.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw Never knew about it.  I don't have any formal training in VB, so I guess I've just never ran across it.  After performing my current refactoring process, I'll do another and see if it would be easier to use the `Collection` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common (though not required) to have a special, reserved node at the start and end of a linked list.  It is typically called a [sentinel node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Sentinel_nodes).

As an aside, I suggest taking the "about 50 functions that modify or otherwise use those linked lists" and moving them to a Class that encapsulates them.

You should not have code that looks like this:

```
Dim theLinkedList as NODE_
Set theLinkedList = New NODE_

'bunch of work with the list
'bunch of work with the list
'bunch of work with the list

Dim theNewNode as NODE_
Set theNewNode = New NODE_
Set theNewNode.Next = someDataObject

Call AppendNode(theLinkedList, theNewNode)
```

Instead the code should just look like this:

```
Dim theList As LinkedList
Set theList = New LinkedList

'etc

Call theList.Append(someDataObject)
```

See the difference?  The LinkedList calss wraps and hides the details.  It can handle things like whether there is a sentinel node at the head or tail as well so that all the rest of your project's code is blissfully unaware.

Comment: Yes, from C++, I know the difference between methods (functions belonging to a class) and regular ol' functions that don't belong to any class.  However, I thought you couldn't do methods in VB6.  Do you have a link to a tutorial?

Comment: Erm, no I don't off hand though I'm sure Google can find something.  I came to VB6 from Java and I coded it just like I would any other OO language for the most part.  To start, add a Class (not module) and declare as Public whatever methods you'd like.  VB6 objects also support a Class_Initialize as your constructor, and Class_Terminate as your destructor.

Comment: Yep, I knew about the constructor/destructor, but for some reason, I thought that's all it supported.  I probably tried to have a second, overloaded constructor with a different parameter signature (or perhaps I changed the parameter-less constructor to one with a parameter), and it errored on me, so I assumed I couldn't write any methods other than the constructor and destructor.  (I guess I didn't read the error message closely enough.)  That's very good news that I can write methods... hopefully it'll help me better organize my code.

Comment: Well, it is still only VB6 so there are some quirks  :)  You only have the default/no-arg constructor.  There are work-arounds for that but generally its not that big of a deal.